# Fancybox JS - jutting across when changing image in gallery

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Using fancybox JS

When images are in a gallery the transition between the images juts the box across the screen a little

see the example gallery example here:
http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

However, on this page:
http://fancybox.net/home

The image gallery transition between the images is smooth and the box stays in the one position.

I cannot figure out how they have managed to get the box to not jut across.

How do I make fancybox keep the box stationary on the screen and not move during transition?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out :)

need to add prevEffect and nextEffect settings in and then it works the way I wanted.

```
$(".lightbox").fancybox({
   'transitionIn'       : 'none',
    'transitionOut'     : 'none',
    'titlePosition'     : 'over',
    'prevEffect'        : 'fade',
    'nextEffect'    : 'fade'

});
```